# Why does CMD+1 work if using my top row numkeys, but not my right-side NumPad? Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, numbers

I use a lot of keyboard shortcuts, like `CMDkey + 1`. However, that `1` has to be from my top row numeric keys. If I try using `CMDkey` plus a number from the NumPad on the right side of my keyboard - this fails. Even though when I plainly type numbers, my NumPad will type the number just like my top row numeric keys.

Why does `CMD+1` work if using my top row numkeys, but not my right-side NumPad?

Comment: In what context? An app? Any app? The key codes are not the same, some apps differentiate, others don't.

Comment: yes, in-app. Specifically, on Google Web Apps and IntelliJ

Comment: Finder is the same. Ctrl/[numpad]1 & Ctrl/1 are not equivalent. Unless the app has slots for more than one shortcut, & also differentiates, you may be stuck with an either/or situation.

Comment: That's very frustrating. A `1` is the same number however I type it.

Comment: same number, but not same key. Sometimes the difference is very useful, other times irritating. I don't think there's a system-wide sitting to en[dis]able that

Comment: It's not even consistent in Adobe CC apps: Illustrator recognizes the keypad but InDesign doesn't when changing the display zoom ratio.

Comment: Is there any way I can have MacOS say a `1` is a `1` regardless of the key that entered it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the kind of person who loves numberpads, but after transitioning to Macbook pro, there's a *thing*.

You see, we all know that Macbooks are made simplistic and adaptable, but it's also similar to Windows keyboard *in* a way.
Do you ever use a Ctrl+1 *from* a numberpad? no. You use it on the number row.
You might've saw my mistake here. Normally there is no Ctrl+1 on Windows unless programmed to do so.

But imagine it like Ctrl+*F1* -  F1 is on the top. So as Macbook keyboards do. But Macs hardly use the F keys unless `fn` is held. Imagine holding that everytime you need to do an action. Fussy fussy. So they use the numbers in the number row instead of the F keys.

So the default *and* easier way is to use the number row instead of the number pad, so that it acts like the F keys on Windows.  - **That's the way of the Apple, easy to use and beautiful looking!**

---

I guess you could program the Mac to use a different shortcut, as mentioned here in [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5720087/how-to-remap-any-keyboard-shortcut-in-mac-os-x) or [iDownloadblog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/11/11/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-specific-commands-in-your-favorite-apps/)

Comment: One of the first things I did was set the F keys to be F1/F2/etc by default.

Comment: Then you may have to manually change the shortcuts to the one on the number pad somehow. The tutorials I provided should do this.